# show data from table php oop

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have some error warning to show my data from database
I have code in folder classes/Comment.php

```
<?php
class Comment
{
protected $database;
public function fetch($table, $rows = '*', $where = null, $order = null)  
{
$result = "SELECT {$rows} FROM {$table}";
if ($where != null) {
  $result += " WHERE {$where}";
}
if ($order != null) {
  $result += " ORDER BY {$order}";
}
return $result;
}
```

in my index.php I wrote:

```
<?php
$comment  = new Comment();
$results = $comment->fetch('', '$tableName', 'id_comment DESC');
$comments = array();
while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
$comments[] = $comment;
}
?>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
    <div class="box-comment">
      <div class="content">
        <?php echo h($comment['content']) ?>      
      </div>
      <div class="date-time">
        <?php echo $comment['posted_at'] ?>     
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

but my code getting error, please help me

Comment: If you can't say *what* error, this is really hard to answer. There's some code here, which is great, but what line is causing the issue?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: the error is "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in line 1", i'm still new in oop

Comment: It means your query failed and you need to check for errors. My advice is to avoid fixing this and switch to PDO before you dig in too deep to `mysql_query` since that's been removed from PHP. PDO supports exceptions which make errors almost impossible to ignore. It also looks like you're constructing some kind of ORM here, but [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) are both good choices if you need one and aren't using a full framework. They're standardized and fully tested so you won't be stuck fussing with problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute first the query. I guess $results return a sql query string, so I suggest you use this:

> $result = mysql_query($results);

Then you can fetch the data using:

> while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { $comments[] =
>   $comment; }

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

My advice to you is to learn mysqli since mysql is now deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0

Tutorials of mysqli: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp